# Mounted Windows share doesn't show contents within docker container?

Tags: mount, samba, docker

I'm using Docker for Windows in WSL (Ubuntu 20.04) and have mounted a shared folder from a Windows 10 machine on my LAN, to the Windows 10 machine that has docker and wsl on it. I did so like this:

`sudo mount -t drvfs '\\192.168.0.195\Music' /media/shares/music`

Now, I am able to see all of those shared directories/files from within wsl itself.

The problem now is, when I mount that directory to a container, like so:

```
      volumes:
        - /media/shares/music:/music
```

the container doesn't see those files? Going inside the container and navigating to the `/music` directory, and doing a `ls` just shows an empty directory.

Any ideas on why this is happening?

Comment: seems like a permissions problem, what user is the container running as? does `ls -laF` show anything?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're using the wrong slashes, you don't need the single quotes and you should probably use cifs

```
sudo mount -t cifs //192.168.0.195/Music /media/shares/music
```

and on the docker-compose side:

```
volumes:
  type: bind
  source: "/media/shares/music"
  target: "/music"
  read_only: true #unless you want to write to it
```

I ran into a similar issue, but in my docker-compose.yml file my volumes had whitespace `"/path/to/source folder"` which needed to be escaped `"/path/to/source\ folder"`